# TeamCity: Compilation error:​ :​app:​compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: teamcity, android-build, android-build-type, android-buildconfig

```
/usr/local/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/app/XXX.java:339: error: cannot find symbol
        if (!original.url().toString().startsWith(BuildConfig.API_OAUTH) && AccessToken.getInstance() != null) { 
                                                             ^ 
  symbol:   variable API_OAUTH 
  location: class BuildConfig
```

TeamCity can't build my Android project. I think that it does not know what kind of build type is needed.
Or am I mistaken and the error in something other?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Yeah, TeamCity didnt know which buildvariants it should to build. 
So i set a special gradle tasks in teamcity's settings.

```
clean assembleProductionRelease testProductionReleaseUnitTest
```